# How do I convert a Elixir tuple into a bitstring?

Tags: types, casting, tuples, elixir

I am new to Elixir and have I am trying to print something to STDOUT using `IO.puts`. `IO.puts` requires chardata. I looked at the Elixir docs and didn't see a way to convert tuples to bitstrings. I know there has to be a way to do this but I haven't found any BIF that do this.

So I want to convert this: `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` to this: `"foobarbaz"`.

I am in the process of learning Elixir and Erlang so this is all pretty new to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Usually we use tuples to hold a fixed amount of data, known up-front. So if you want to print the contents of a tuple, I would recommend doing:

```
def print_tuple({ foo, bar, baz }) do
  IO.puts foo <> bar <> baz
end
```

If the tuple you want to print has a dynamic size, it is very likely you want to use a list instead. You can convert the elements of a list to a binary using many functions, for example, `Enum.join/2`:

```
IO.puts Enum.join(list)
```

If you are absolutely sure you want to print the tuple contents, you can do:

```
IO.puts Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(tuple))
```

Keep in mind you can print any Elixir data structure by using `IO.inspect/1`.

Comment: Since Elixir v0.13.3 it's `Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(tuple))`.

Answer (score 14):

[`Enum.join`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#join/2) creates a bitstring composed of the consecutive elements of a list. Convert the tuple to a list first. Using [the `|>` (pipe) operator](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#the-pipe-operator) may improve readability:

```
{"foo", "bar", "baz"} |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.join  # "foobarbaz"
```

You can also specify a delimiter:

```
{"foo", "bar", "baz"} |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.join(", ")  # "foo, bar, baz"
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
def concat_binaries(binaries) do
    List.foldr(binaries, <<>>, fn(a, b) -> <<a :: binary, b :: binary>> end)
end

tuple = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
IO.puts(concat_binaries(tuple_to_list(tuple)))
```